# Which two would be an example of non-equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Additionally, it's required that neither of them induces the discrete topology.

Comment: what all metrics do you know on $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following metric is not topologically equivalent to the standard Euclidean metric:

$$d ( x , y ) = \begin{cases}
\min \{ | x - y |,1\}, &\text{if }x,y\text{ are either both rational or both irrational} \\
1, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

(The underlying idea can be used to generate *lots* of inequivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Thank you, that was an interesting example.