# $f(x)=x$ can be descontinuous?

Tags: metric-spaces

In metric space, the continuity of a function depends on a metric. Can I define some metric $(\mathbb{R},d_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R},d_2)$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x$ is descontinuous? I've tried zero-one metric for $d_1$ and maximum metric for $d_2$, but zero-one is all isolated points so is continuous at every point.

Comment: All metrics are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces

Comment: @mnp That's not true at all.  Consider the discrete metric versus the usual one.

Comment: Try $d_2$ the zero-one (a.k.a. discrete) metric, and $d_1 \neq d_2$.

Comment: @mnp all norms are equivalent. Not all metrics

Comment: Then, only the metrics that can be induced by norms are equivalent?

Comment: @mnp No (whatever that means), it is not an iff

Comment: @azif00 Of course, thank you.

Comment: @EmanuelDias This also answers your question [Which two would be an example of non-equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649776/which-two-would-be-an-example-of-non-equivalent-metrics-on-mathbbr)

Comment: That's weird. All norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces. So, they all should induce equivalent metrics? @AnneBauval

Comment: @mnp Yes they do.

Comment: Then we have a theorem that we can use to build a set S that contains only those metrics that can be induced by a norm.  And so, only the metrics in S would be equivalent in any finite dimensional space? @AnneBauval

Comment: Given a metric you can always define a bounded euivalent metric. So given a norm induced metric you have an equivalent metric which is bounded hence not norm induced

Comment: @mnp No, again, it is not an if and only if: there are metrics on your finite dimensional space which are not induced by a norm and which are nevertheless equivalent. Moreover, I said "whatever it means" because there are numerous equivalence classes of metrics, and each of them is infinite.